# Give a proof of validity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm doing an exercise from the book of the following:

1. $p \leftrightarrow q$
2. $\sim p$
3. $(q\land\sim\!r)\lor t$
4. $(s\lor t)\to r$

conclusion: $r\land\sim\!q$

I applied the biconditional law on the first premise, but seem to be stuck there. Can you guys push me in the right direction?

Comment: What set of rules are you using ?

Comment: Laws of statement logic and rules of inference

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Clearly 2nd premise $\lnot p$ implies that (1st premise) $\lnot q$ must be true, and thus (3rd premise) also $t$ will be true. Thus, conclusion follows using 4th premise.

Comment: There's more than one set of laws of statement logic and of rules of inference.

Comment: Also, which book are you referring to?

Comment: Mathematical Methods in Linguistics.

Comment: And how does the 2nd premise imply that ~q must be true? Sorry I'm really new to logic!

Comment: Because $p \leftrightarrow q$ means that either both true or both false. If $\lnot p$ is true (it is a premise), thus also $\lnot q$ is.

Comment: how would I write that down with the logical laws?

Comment: We still do not know what rules to use...

Comment: I end up with the conclusion of Mauro, $\neg q$. I am not able to produce $r$ to conclude $r\wedge\neg q$, although the reasoning is valid...

Comment: Is the answer below enough for you ? If so, you can accept it and we can "close" the post.

Comment: It's perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

From 1st premise: $p ↔ q$, by [Bi-conditional elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_elimination) we get $q → p$ and using Contraposition we have $¬p → ¬q$.

Thus, by Modus Ponens with 2nd premise: $¬q$.

Using [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) we get: $\lnot q \lor r$, and by De Morgan: $\lnot (q \land \lnot r)$.

Thus, $t$ follows from 3rd premise using [Disjunctive Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism).

Now the conclusion is straightforward.

Comment: Aha, you used your deduction of $\neg q$ to find $r$, when I have not work with that! +++1.

Comment: Just inspect your target, $\neg q$ and $r$, and the premises: $1.~p\leftrightarrow q$, $2.~\neg p$, $3.~(q\wedge\neg r)\vee t$, and $4.~(s\vee t)\to r$. Clearly you may derive $r$ from premise 4 *if* you can derive $s$ or $t$. Now $s$ is not mentioned elsewhere, but $t$ occurs in premise 3, so you may derive it if you can *deny* $(q\land\neg r)$. Well, since you are already trying to affirm $r$, that leaves denying $q$ as the only path. That is okay, since the first and the second premise are all that you need to do so.  Thus you *must* first derive $\neg q$, and next use *that* to derive $r$.

Comment: The comment should have been directed @manooooh.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamKemp for such explanation!!